# How can I play an embedded youtube iframe video at a specific time?

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, youtube

How can I embed a Youtube Video with the iframe API with start and end time?

How can I play the video at a specific start time til specific end time?

Here is the Google example, I couldn't understand:

```
loadVideoById({'videoId': 'bHQqvYy5KYo',
           'startSeconds': 5,
           'endSeconds': 60,
           'suggestedQuality': 'large'});
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en

Here is the fiddle (line 43-47) http://jsfiddle.net/8R5y6/357/

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to pass a **playerVars** object that has the **start** and **end** parameters set when creating the player.

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      },
      playerVars: {
         start: 5,
         end: 60
      }
    });
```

Although please note that in your JSFiddle example, the `onPlayerStateChange` function stops the video after 6 seconds of play.

Comment: True, the 6 second thing is from googles example. Not that important.
Ok thx.
And how can I do this function:
function startPlayingAtStopAt(startTime,endTime);  
I know the endTime could be done with a setTimeout(); but I want those markers in the youtube video. (like this: https://www.youtube.com/v/chElHV99xak?start=53&end=59)